# A Perl or Gawk script that returns a Keyword, the word before, and the word after?

Tags: perl, search, gawk

I need a simple script to run in Windows that searches **large** xml files for a keyword, then returns the word before it, the keyword, and the word after.

For example:
"How can I extract **keywords** in context"
I want:
"extract **keywords** in"

I'm a novice with enough knowledge to return each *line* with the Keyword, and the *lines* before and after, but I'm stumped on getting the individual words I need out.

Anyone have any clever ideas?

Comment: what should it return if there *is no* word before ("keywords" at beginning of file)? Same if at end of file...

Comment: What does "word" mean when you say it? What should the word before be for "A sentence, keywords should be found"? Should it be "," or "sentence" or "sentence,"?

Comment: Well, "word" means exactly that in this context, though the possibility of <tag>tagging</tag> exists, since it's XML.  As such, I'd want whatever combination of whitespace-free-characters exist prior to and following the whitespaces around "Keyword".  If nothing precedes or follows "keyword", then nothing need be returned (or "null", whatever).

Comment: To answer your question, tadmc, "sentence," "keywords" and "should".  Would need to be returned. So keyword, whitespace, and character block before next whitespace.

Comment: So, since a "word" is \S+, then "keywords=none" contains no match for "keywords"? "sentence," is not a word, so it does NOT mean "exactly that"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.12.0;
my $keyword = 'keywords';

while (<DATA>)
{
    say for /\b(\S+\s+\b\Q$keyword\E[[:punct:]]*\s+\S+)\b/g;
}

__END__
How can I extract keywords in context, even if there are many keywords to
extract? So many keywords, no idea how to deal with them.
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -o` is enough:

```
grep -Po '(\S+\s)?keywords(\s\S+)?' << END
How can I extract keywords in context
How can I extract keywords
keywords in context
END
```

returns

```
extract keywords in
extract keywords
keywords in
```

Comment: Not natively, but [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) can be installed.

Comment: Fun bit about regexes... they match only what you tell it to. (See my example text below - your regex would miss the one with the comma - not sure if that's desired or not.)

Comment: @Tanktalus - Heeeey, just got yours going as well (which I'll probably stick with).  I had to enable the "say" feature and divert output to a text file (15k+ results...), but that did the trick.  Thanks to you both!